# Mock a Function which is called inside a Golang Http Hander

Tags: go, mocking

I have a function need to be tested, which looks like this:

```
func parmHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   ...
   data, err = backenddb_call(r *http.Request)
   ...
   return
}


function backenddb_call(r *http.Request) (data []Data, err error){
   parm := r.URL.Query().Get(parm)
   //Get Data from DB for parm 
   ...
   return
}
```

In this HTTP handler case, I cannot modify the `parmHandler` arguments and add a helper interface argument to help with mocking. How can I mock backenddb_call to return different responses?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a function which returns your handler, which you pass the `backenddb_call` as an argument to:

https://play.golang.org/p/aSMxeEgJL8U

```
func GetHandler(fn func (r *http.Request) ([]Data, error)) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data, err := fn(r)
        fmt.Println(data, err)
    })
}
```

Then, when you create it:

```
http.HandleFunc("/test", GetHandler(backenddb_call))
```

and to test it you can just pass in a different call:

```
GetHandler(func (r *http.Request) ([]Data, error) {
    fmt.Println("Mock")
    return []Data{"This", "Is", "A", "Fake", "Response"}, nil
})
```